# Generic methods

Tags: java

I need to send an integer array and a string array to this generic method and find out if a certain number or string is present there or not.I wrote this code but it is giving an error on the line `if(e==30)` saying that "`Incompatible operand types E and int`". Please help.

```
public class Ch2Lu3Ex2
 {
   public static <E> void searchArray(E[] inputArray)
   {
    for(E e : inputArray)
     {
       if(e==30)
         {
          System.out.println("Element found in integer array");
         }
       else if(e=="raj")
         {
           System.out.println("Element found in string array");
         }

     }
  } 

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       Integer[] integerArray = {10,20,30};
       String[] stringArray = {"robin","raj","ravi"};
       searchArray(integerArray);
       searchArray(stringArray);
    }
  }
```

Comment: There are many things wrong here, fist of them being that you should (almost) never compare objects using `==` but with `equals()`, and secondly  you don't need generics at all for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes, both of them must be fixed:

1) fix it like: `if(e instanceof Integer && (Integer)e==30)` - you have to check, that `e` is an instance of `Integer`

2) `String`s must be compared using `equals` method:

`else if(e.equals("raj"))`

Comment: Integer should be compared with equals too.

Comment: @assylias, I don't agree. In this case comparing with `(int)` constant, so it is ok.

Comment: Good point, the Integer will get unboxed and `==` will compare `ints`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't know if `e` is an `Integer` or a `String`, and you can't compare a `String` with an `Integer` and vice versa.

One solution would be to pass the sought item to your method too - it could look like this:

```
public static <E> void searchArray(E[] inputArray, E soughtItem) {
    for (E e : inputArray) {
        if (e.equals(soughtItem)) {
            System.out.println("Element found in integer array");
        }
    }
}
```

And in your main code:

```
searchArray(integerArray, 30);
searchArray(stringArray, "raj");
```

Also note that you should use `equals` instead of `==` for equality tests.

Finally, all this has already been written by others:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String> (stringArray);
if (set.contains("raj")) System.out.println("Found raj");
```

Comment: Or simply: `public static void searchArray(Object[] inputArray, Object soughtItem)`

Comment: @biziclop your method can then be called: `searchArray(someIntegerArray, "ABC");` which is probably something you want to prevent at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "==" when you compare objects! Change to "equals()" method and should work!

```
public class Ch2Lu3Ex2
 {
   public static <E> void searchArray(E[] inputArray)
   {
    for(E e : inputArray)
     {
       if(e.equals(30))
         {
          System.out.println("Element found in integer array");
         }
       else if("raj".equals(e)) //This way no null pointer will occure
         {
           System.out.println("Element found in string array");
         }

     }
  } 

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       Integer[] integerArray = {10,20,30};
       String[] stringArray = {"robin","raj","ravi"};
       searchArray(integerArray);
       searchArray(stringArray);
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for the null-pointer observation. Why not apply the same logic to the e.equals(30)? You will get a null-pointer there too, and also before it hits the second comparison :-P